# Is it possible to send facebook Apps invite with message and avoid notify user who already use app

Tags: facebook

I would like to avoid a notify to user who already use this app and after the invitee accept the invitation both of them get reward.
I use facebook Requests Dialog it allow user to choose all of his/her friend and cannot display invite message, I store all invitees id to database when they join the game they get reward.
Here my code.

```
function facebookInvite(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Please join, and we’ll both get free items!”',
        data: encode(Player.id)
    }, function(response) { 
        if(response && response.request){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "call/request.php",
                data: {
                    from : Player.id,
                    to : response.to.join(),
                }   
            });            
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to send facebook Apps invite with message

No, on invites – that is a user-to-user request to a user who is not already a user of your app – the message will not get shown, they will just receive a notification saying *“X invited to you use app/play game foo.”*

> and avoid notify user who already use app

See `filters` parameter of the Request dialog; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: I'm not sure if it because I'm in sandbox mode but when I use
filters: ['app_non_users'] 
I can avoid app user in the list but when I type name and search.
App user appear and when after I send Requests he got notification

Comment: Hm … hard to tell, if this is worth opening a bug report – or if Facebook will just answer that with their usual _“that’s by design”_ response phrase. Your other option would be to create your own friend selector, and therein only offer a choice of users that are not users of your app yet, and call the request dialog with the chosen user ids afterwards - see here for an example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/